# How to revert project back to a previous commit in android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am working on a project in android studio and would like to revert to a previous push. I attempted
VCS => Git => Reset Head (Hard)
but my project in Android Studio is unchanged, likely because I'm doing something wrong. I would like to revert the project in Android Studio to a specific earlier commit that I've pushed and I see on github. I do not care about any changes that I have made since the earlier push.
Additionally, I would like this to be done through the GUI within Android Studio if possible.

Comment: Have you tried clicking right click on the commit name in the version control tab/Log? There should be _Reset Branch to here_

Comment: I had not. Prior to this post I didn't know the version control tab log existed.

Comment: Read all about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**Android Studio Instructions**: if you want to do this in Android Studio, press `alt + 9` (or `Command + 9` on Mac) to open the Version Control panel. Switch to the `Log` tab and right click on a previous commit. Select `Checkout Revision`.

---

**Command line instructions**: Open the command line tool you are using.
Go to the Android app's Git directory (using `cd`).
Execute `git log` and find the previous commit you want to revert to.

```
commit 7c247be6d8975dc88f6cc2631c154786a1f3b79e
Author: John Doe <john@doe.ca>
Date:   Fri Jun 11 22:37:35 2015 -0400

    Some helpful commit message should be here.
```

If that is the commit you want to revert to, then execute `git checkout 7c247b`.

Comment: I apologize for not making the question more clear. I would like to do this through android studio and not the command line. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Updated with Android Studio instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much. It saved much of my time!

Comment: I do checkout Revision and it give me detach head state

Comment: Thanks for the Mac keyboard shortcuts!

Answer (score 32):

Open the Version Control Panel using `alt + 9` and click on Log. This should show a list of commits. Right click on the commit you want to revert to and select `Reset Current Branch to Here`. This should bring up a list of options to keep or discard changes when reverting. Select `Hard` to discard any current changes and click Reset.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

The icon surrounded by red rectangle in image will do the trick

Comment: This doesn't revert to a specific commit as the question asks.

Comment: Thanks, it does help to roll back to the last commit.

Answer (score 10):

1. In android studio 4.0, go to version control -> Log.
2. Then select the commit you want to revert to.
3. Choose Reset current branch to here.
4. You ll see a popup, select Hard and its done.

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio -> Version Control -> Select your commit -> Right panel -> Select you want to be reverted file.

[image]

Then you can get the new reverted change, commit -> done.

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio > check bottom toolbar -> click on git -> select log tab -> right on particular commit -> reset current branch to here -> select hard reset

Also if u have already pushed code to server
u need to run

```
git push -f origin branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

MacOS users

Rollback Changes

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

```
VCS -> Git -> Rollback...
//or
VCS Local  Changes Toolbar -> Rollback...
//or
Commit Changes -> Rollback...
```

Answer (score 0):

While push is selected branch to undo;
example brach name -> push_will_be_undone

```
git push -f origin push_will_be_undone
```

Writing did my job and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

use the below command

```
git revert <hashString of the commit that you wanted to go on>
```

Answer (score -5):

Right click on folder where you Github folder, press `Git Bash Here` and type `git reset --hard`

Comment: "Reset" is not a "revert". Even if your local files seem to be reset to the previous commit. Other users who have pulled your "reset" commit will see it in their history