# How to use a previous Git commit as a new version of the master branch in Android Studio?

Tags: git

[How do I restore a previous version as a new commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727750/how-do-i-restore-a-previous-version-as-a-new-commit-in-git) is exactly what I want but my question is related to Android Studio.

I have done exactly the solution in the answer to the question: checking out a previous version. However, there is a warning at the bottom of Android Studio:

> Git: Detached HEAD doesn't point to any branch

[image]

I hesitate to move forward from this point. I want this checked-out version to be a new version of the master branch.

Could anyone offer a tip on how to make this a new version of the master branch with Android Studio?

I learned that the checkout I did is not exactly what the solution suggests. Here are the Git options for a commit:

[image]

Which one corresponds to the suggested solution - commit with a trailing "."?

Is it "Reset Current Branch to Here..."?

Right now the Git commit history looks like this:

```
V2.2
V2.1
V2.0
V1.5
V1.4
...
```

I want to check out V1.4, then make some changes by comparing it with V2.2 and make this history look like the following after committing the new version:

```
V3.0
V2.2
V2.1
V2.0
V1.5
V1.4
...
```

Comment: Apparently you did `git checkout <commit>` but the accepted answer to the question you have linked suggests to do `git checkout <commit> .` - note the trailing dot. You are not in the position you want to be in. Go back to `master` and start over.

Comment: The equivalent to `git checkout <commit> .` is not listed as one of the options in the menu you have shown.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It is hard to explain things in a comment, so I edited my question primarily to respond to your comment.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you for clarifying this. Does it mean it is impossible to achieve what I need with Android Studio's UI?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to restore an old version is to use this command:

```
git reset --hard 0ad5a7a6
```

There are two options for reset: `--soft` and `--hard`.
When you use `--soft` git retains the changes from the undone commits as local modifications.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163380/how-to-revert-project-back-to-a-previous-commit-in-android-studio) too.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Does this reset keep all the commit history?

Comment: No, you will be committed in 0ad5a7a6.
If you want to keep the commit history, just create a new branch to reset your branch to a specific commit:
git checkout -b your-branch-name 0ad5a7a6

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It seems that I cannot do this with Android UI.

Comment: You're welcome!